# UICollectionView with dynamic content(variable amount of views for each cell)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to create a collection view with each cell being like the picture below:

[image]

The thing is that each cell is going to have a variable amount of "events". One can have just 2 and another one can have up to 10 or so.

I can't find a way to make this possible, mainly because I think I would have to make a UITableView with each cell being a UICollectionView. But how can I set the height differently for each of the cells. And I think it would also be an overkill.

What would be the way to go for? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have few options:

- create completely custom layout class - child of
  UICollectionViewLayout (UICollectionViewFlowLayout) (most likely you wont do that)
- in case You are using UICollectionViewFlowLayout implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol that contains method for sizing cells:

> ```
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
>                     layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
>                     sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
> ```

and calculate height of the cell depending on amount of events you have for a date

- create two kind of cells — one for a cell with date and one event (toppest in a day), another for just event (maybe some others, like separators or something, depending on UI). Both of the cells have fixed height so using method from UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout you can provide correct sizes for cells.

**p.s** in all cases first what you have to think is — what's your model, what's the next step (like for example — will there be an open event animation, can you swipe to delete event, can you interact with each event, etc) — depending on that you have to choose between 2nd and 3rd option

Comment: Thanks! I used your third approach. I created a single UICollectionView and two types of views. First one with just the date and the other with event. And just added events or titles as needed. Of course data in my model needs to be sorted.